# issue with spread operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to rewrite an array and to get a new one at  the final.
This is my code:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"
  },
  {
    type:"ford", model:"5300", color:"gray"
  }
];
const newArr = arr.map(i => {
    const r = {
      ...arr,
      power:2
    }
    return r
})



console.log(newArr)
```

Now i get the wrong result, because one every iteration, the new array grow with a copy of the first array:

```
 const r = {
    ...arr,
    power:2
 }
```

How to get the next result?

```
{
  type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white", power: 2
},
{
  type:"ford", model:"5300", color:"gray", power: 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are spreading `arr` .You need to spread `i` which is the object inside the array.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"
  },
  {
    type:"ford", model:"5300", color:"gray"
  }
];
const newArr = arr.map(i => {
    const r = {
      ...i,
      power:2
    }
    return r;
})
console.log(newArr)
```

With array function you can implicitly

```js
const arr = [
  {
    type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"
  },
  {
    type:"ford", model:"5300", color:"gray"
  }
];
const newArr = arr.map(i => ({...i, power: 2}));
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to spread the current object that you are getting as:

```
const newArr = arr.map(i => ({ ...i, power: 2 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do this, you are spreading `arr` and should be spreading the array getting passed to `map` (e.g. `i`):

```
const newArr = arr.map(i => {
    const r = {
      ...i,
      power:2
    }
    return r
})
```